# Does fluentd supports protobuf message in the HTTP input?

Tags: protocol-buffers, fluentd

Is it possible to send protobuf messages to Fluentd?

I'm not asking for protobuf parsing, just receive the protobuf and send it to an output.

Config example:

```
<source>
# Here I would receive the protobuf message
@type http
port 9880
bind 0.0.0.0
body_size_limit 32m
keepalive_timeout 10s
</source>

<match hello>
# And here I'd send the protobuf message to another endpoint
@type http

endpoint "http://localhost:9999"
open_timeout 2

<buffer>
flush_interval 1s
</buffer>
</match>
```

With this configuration, fluentd answers:

```
400 Bad Request
'json' or 'msgpack' parameter is required
```

Comment: Why HTTP input? Is there any specific reason? What was the message that you tested and it resulted in Bad Request? That looks like it wasn't a well-formed HTTP request. Please add your test message in the question.

Comment: According to your configuration and defaults, it should be something like this: `http://localhost:9880/hello?json=<protobuf-message-here>`.

Comment: If you're still looking, take a look at this [fluent-plugin-protobuf-http](https://github.com/iamAzeem/fluent-plugin-protobuf-http).

Comment: @Azeem your plugin looks pretty promising, that looks like it would fit my use cases. I'll give it a try. Please put it in as answer and I'll mark it as the solution

Comment: Sure. Please do. Your feedback would be appreciated and helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [fluent-plugin-protobuf-http](https://github.com/iamAzeem/fluent-plugin-protobuf-http) for single/batch input protocol buffers' messages encoded according to custom-defined schemas (`.proto` files).